# How to find record between canadian zip code range

Tags: php, mysql, range, zipcode

I want to find all records between two Canadian zip codes.

I have used:

```
SELECT count(*) as target FROM `subscribers` WHERE (zipcode BETWEEN "A0A1A0" AND "A0A2A9" )
```

this query does not give me the right output. Can anyone help?

Comment: try this SELECT count(*) as target FROM subscribers WHERE (zipcode like  "A0A%" )

Comment: i think thats not how  `BETWEEN` works...is there nothing else column to group the records, like `WHERE country='CANADA'`, or something...?

Comment: use `zipcode LIKE '%A0A%'` is way easier...nice @Rakesh

Comment: Actually, if Canadian zipcodes always follow this format (6 characters, letter followed by digit) then I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: @1000111 er, no you don't

Comment: @J.Zend '%A0A%' is a good way but it select all pincodes like A2A0A1 and think this zipcode is of outside Canada.

Comment: then just use `LIKE 'A0A%'` if Canada zipCode start with A0A,,,

Comment: is Canada zip code always start with `A0A` and followed by three letters ?

Comment: thanks for you answer but i did not get actual result as  my requirement is suppose i am admin and i am putting gift for all user  whose zipcode  BETWEEN "A0A1A0" AND "A0A2A9"   , and i have one user whose zipcode  is A0A1A5 so he receive a gift as he fulfill the criteria

Comment: @HirenMakwana currently what result your query gives, and what it should be? just describe bit brief in your question

Comment: `SELECT 'A0A1A5' BETWEEN 'A0A1A0' AND 'A0A2A9'` returns `1` (true) for me as expected. Can you provide some examples of zipcodes which incorrectly match or do not match?

Answer (score 0):

If the zipcode is properly  assigned .. you can use the query without  ()

```
SELECT count(*) as target 
FROM `subscribers` 
WHERE  zipcode BETWEEN "A0A1A0" AND "A0A2A9" ;
```

eventually you cant performa trim for remove invisible char

```
SELECT count(*) as target 
FROM `subscribers` 
WHERE  trim(zipcode)  BETWEEN "A0A1A0" AND "A0A2A9" ;
```